# jQuery is not defined twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting this error that says jQuery is not defined. I want to use twitter bootstrap and jQuery-UI. In my `<head>` I've added the CSS and JS necessary. I noticed that the jQuery-UI page uses 1.9.1 jQuery and the latest version is 1.10.2. So I'm assuming there is some sort of conflict going on. Twitter bootstrap requires jQuery so that might be causing the error. Or perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined          bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function)                                    bootstrap.min.js:6
```

[image]

Comment: Jquery needs to be listed before bootstrap.

Comment: Why are you including two versions of jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 Well the jQuery UI site linked to use that version and I looked up some information about JS backward compatibility. I read that it is good but there can sometimes be errors so I included both.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Load jQuery before everything else!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: ALways load CSS before JS

Comment: Ideally you would load javascript after your HTML so just before `</body>` - it's not used until then and it speeds up page load that way.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have jQuery before Bootstrap and get the error anyway!

Comment: why you have call jquery  serveral times.Can you please  explain?

Comment: @tymeJV  - much appreciated ! :D

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely because of 2 reasons:

1. You are loading jQuery twice; remove one of them (preferably the older version).
2. You are loading bootstrap.min.js before loading jQuery (read the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)).

What you need to do is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" />
```

Comment: Loading bootstrap.min.js before jQuery was my issue it would seem. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

add jquery js file above bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

I've tested this and this order seems to work the best.

1. Load CSS
2. Load jQuery
3. Load **Bootstrap**
4. Load jQuery UI