# Visual Studio throwing exceptions when using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, internet-explorer

Coding ASP.net web app with visual studio, i never had any problem when chrome or firefox is the default explorer. But when it's IE, a new project called `Script documents` suddently appear in my project explorer and visual studio always shows that exception in the new project for every pages load :

`JavaScript execution error: Unable to get the property "tagName" of a null or undefined reference`

Which doesn't prevent the web app to work, it's just annoying to have to click on the window in visual studio every time i switch pages while debuging.

The window offers me to Stop, Continue, or Ignore.

Ignore make the window reappear instantly, continue make it disapear for a little while...

Haven't found anything that solve it on google, neither in here.

How can this be solved ? And how is explorer so different ?

---

Edit :

Taking this as an exemple, i'm pretty sure it SHOULD work :

[jQuery is not defined twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502838/jquery-is-not-defined-twitter-bootstrap)

And still, the window always pop-up in my IE 11, saying that it haven't foud the `tagName` property.

So now my new question is, do i have to specify the tag name of every object because i use boothstrap ? Or is it something else that cause the problem ?

---

EDIT :

This is the Master Page's codes :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Canevas.master.cs" Inherits="MandatMobile.Canevas" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Menu.ascx" TagPrefix="ctrl" TagName="Menu" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" >
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

    <form runat="server" style="position:absolute; left:10px;">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/Fullogo.jpg" ></asp:Image>


    <h2 style="position:absolute; top:-5px; left:120px; width:1200px;" >
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="title" runat="server" >
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </h2> 

   <%if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Level"]) != 1)
    { %>

    <div style="position:absolute; top:110px; left:0px;">
    <ctrl:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" ></ctrl:Menu>
</div>

<% } %>

<br /><br /><br /><br />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContent" runat="server" >
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

  </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

SOLVED :

---

It was ridiculus... there was another menu before i build this one, what i did was put the previous menu in HTML comment and code my new menu on the same page, but the menu in comment was still up and even though it was in comment  it was still looking for it's references, just like it WASEN'T in comment... What the... i think that is going to be my new question

Comment: chrome will show up that same error on the console!

Comment: locate the line where the error spawns and prevent the error via `if(...)`or `try { ... } catch { ... }`

Comment: It dosen't shows in my code, it's a part of code that apear when i debug, and that part of code apear only if IE is my default navigator... weird

Comment: Check JS files reference order, it might be because some plugin might be reading 'tagname'. Chrome also behaves similar but it wont popup IE alert kind window

Comment: @MithunPattankar i have these kind of ref script that enhance visual aspect of the web content : <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  if i remove them, no more error message, but no style

Comment: [Check this](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.in/2010/03/css-ie8-meta-tag-to-disable.html) try this for IE11

Comment: Could you post your code? I found a similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865168/ie-throwing-javascript-typeerror-but-not-on-chrome?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Post your code, without it, it's impossible to help fix the error.

Comment: I'd like to take a look into this, can you post your code please?

Comment: @Richard here is the code.

Comment: @DavidG for you too, if you need anything else just ask i will be watching for comments

Comment: your question improperly scopes your issue, I think... an issue that isn't with this snippet, per say... show us `~/Controls/Menu.ascx`.. markup and code-behind. Note that web browsers will only interpret/process the outputted markup. your error is a runtime issue, which is likely in a script reference in the user-defined custom control, or something that is being injected in your code-behind.  By the way, this is the master page template is seems.. where is the content page, and does it specify scripts?

Comment: `TagName` is not to be confused with `tagName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok A lot of questions lets answer one by one:

> "But when it's IE, a new project called Script documents suddently appear in my project explorer ..."

This project as you called, is a mechanism of visual studio that allows the developers debug javascript in the IDE (Visual Studio), but this only work for IE, because, as long as I know, there wasn't no interesting from Microsoft (or the browsers creators) to make it work for other browsers.

If you want to understand better what is it and how to use, enable, disable see this post: [Using Visual Studio to Debug JavaScript in IE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18921/Using-Visual-Studio-to-Debug-JavaScript-in-IE).

> "...and visual studio always shows that exception in the new project for every pages load :"

As [@Mithun Pattankar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5332695/mithun-pattankar) commented in your question, probably this exception occurs in other browsers too, but when you use chrome or firefox, you will get this exception more quietly. To see you have to go to DevTools (F12 in chrome) or some other custom tool, only then will see it.

But because you have the debug javascript in VS enabled, when you used the IE, the exception was thrown in VS instead of the browser.

> And still, the window always pop-up in my IE 11, saying that it haven't foud the tagName property.
>
> So now my new question is, do i have to specify the tag name of every object because i use boothstrap ?

Ok some misguidance here. First the problem isn't with the `tagName` property. Let me explain:

The message error that you got was `"Unable to get the property "tagName" of a null or undefined reference"`. See the code bellow:

```
var v1 = { aGenericPropertyName: 10 };

v1.aGenericPropertyName = 20;

var v2 = v1.aGenericPropertyName;

v1 = null;
//or:
v1 = undefined;

var v3 = v1.aGenericPropertyName;
```

In the last line, depending on the browser, you may get this exception:

`"Unable to get the property "aGenericPropertyName" of a null or undefined reference."`

Did you get it now? The problem isn't the property, is the object that call the property or more accuracy the absence of an object (null or undefined) in a variable (in my sample code the variable v1).

> Or is it something else that cause the problem ?

Well here's the real problem, because this kind of error can occur basically in any part of any javascript code that you added to the page. So it's not possible to solve this only by looking superficially.

I have some suggestions if you want to try. First, make sure you have the correct files of bootstrap.js and jquery.js and they are compatible between itself. Second check if this error is occurring in one of your custom javascript files.

Beyond that we will only be able to help you, if you post the exact line of the exception and how file the error occurs.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty good answer, i was able to locate the exact location of the problem by removing different parts of javascripts codes, couldn't solve it yet, but at least i know what is the issu, it's my menu, I'll accept your answer when i can, in the meantime, i'll try to find how to solve the problematic part